# Generalized Black Scholes PDE in a Two Factor model

Tags: black-scholes, correlation, black-scholes-pde, differential-equations

I'm reading the book of Clewlow and Strickland on Energy derivatives. In the section about the two-factor model, an equation, similar to B&S PDE is presented, but the proof is not presented.

Spot dynamics:
$$ dS=(r-\delta)S dt + \sigma S dW $$
Convenience yield dynamics:
$$ d\delta= \alpha(\hat{\delta}-\delta) dt + \sigma_\delta dW_{\delta}$$
$$ dW dW_{\delta} = \rho dt $$
The book says: *The joint process for the spot and the convenience yield lead to the following differential equation for contingent claim prices:*
$$ 1/2  C_{SS} S^2\sigma^2 + 1/2  C_{\delta \delta} \sigma^2_{\delta} + C_{S \delta} S \rho \sigma \sigma_\delta + C_S S(r-\delta) + C_{\delta}( \alpha(\hat{\delta}-\delta_t) - \lambda_\delta \sigma_\delta) + C_t = 0 $$
*Where $\lambda_\delta $ is the market price of risk per unit of convenience yield.*

I have the feeling that a term in the equation is missing ($-rC $), but I can't find anywhere on the web proof of this equation!
Could you please provide me a reference book or paper where I can find the proof of it?

Thank you in advance